# Haskell library for parsing Bash scripts?

Tags: bash, parsing, haskell

Does anybody know of a Haskell library which can parse arbitrary Bash scripts?

A cursory search of Hackage indicates that there's a package called `bash` for *writing* scripts, but I don't see anything for *parsing* them.

Basically I've just had a large collection of Bash scripts dumped on me, and I'd like to do some code analysis on it. But the first stage is obviously to be able to parse this stuff.

I don't know Bash very well personally. I suppose I *could* sit down and wage through the volumous man-page to get the complete BNF grammar for it. (I imagine it's very complex, given the shell's long and backwards-compatible history.) I was just wondering whether somebody else has already done this work for me...

Comment: Best of luck. You will need it if you are going to write the parser yourself.

Comment: I think you would be better off trying to look at the bash code and working from the parser there.  The likelihood of there being a Haskell bash parser in existence seems remote.  There are possible libraries that you could use natively from Haskell to get an AST. Possibilities: [libbash](http://dev.gentoo.org/~qiaomuf/libbash.html); [jBash](http://code.google.com/p/jbash/); [someone else wanting to write a parser](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=101893), etc.

Comment: Are they bash scripts or shell scripts?  Because POSIX shell syntax is simpler and the parsing algorithm is described in the spec on opengroup.

Comment: The yacc file in bash source code is 6000 lines long, and seems to have a fair amount of hackery. But I think the [BNF itself](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/operating-systems-and-server-administration/unix/1565923472/syntax/lbs.appd.div.3) is not that bad.

Comment: @singpolyma Is there a way to reliably distinguish them? (E.g., Is the shebang line reliable? I thought `sh` is usually a symlink to `bash` anyway?)

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid `sh` is not normally a symlink to `bash`, though I believe it is on OSX and some other systems.  Debian has a `checkbashisms` tool that is pretty good.  The most commonly used extension is `[[`

Comment: @singpolyma The script I have definitely contains copious usage of `[[`. So, yes, I guess it _is_ Bash...

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps extend [language-sh](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/language-sh).

> Language.Sh is a collection of modules for parsing and manipulating
>   expressions in shell grammar. This is part of a larger project, shsh.
>   Please note that the API is somewhat unstable until we reach version
>   1.0.